# Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke - Where to place Try & catch?

Tags: .net, wpf, try-catch

if I have a dispatcher invoking in background like this:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MethodToCall()), DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

Should I have wrap the code above inside a Try & catch or place the try & catch inside the `MethodToCall()` method?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really have a case for catching a *specific* exception then the `try { } catch` should be placed inside `MethodToCall`.

Answer (score 3):

Hi BeginInvoke will Execute your Method in anoster Stack.
So a try-catch around "Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke" will not work.

You need to do something like this:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
try
{
    MethodToCall();
}
catch
{
   //handle
}
), DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

or simply in "MethodToCall".

As ChrisF stated.