# Where to put try-catch when calling Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a question similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586006/application-current-dispatcher-begininvoke-where-to-place-try-catch). But in my case, it is not the BeginIvnoke method, it is the Invoke method. I need to wrap my code in the try-catch statement, but not sure exactly where to put it.

Here is my code:

```
private void UpdateUI()
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        if (SecurityComponent.CurrentLoggedUser != null)
        {
            var user = SecurityComponent.CurrentLoggedUser;
                m_userLabel.Text = user.Username + " - " + user.Role.Name;
        }                
        UpdateTerritories();
        ViewsIntegrationService.SetHmiMode(EHmiModes.Normal);
    });
}
```

Comment: Once you wrap your code in a try catch, what are you planning on doing? What error are you expecting? Is there definitely no way to avoid that error in the first place?

Comment: For now, the goal is to display a MessageBox with the error message. Right now, without any error-handling, the application crashes. The methods called are not under my control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You catch the exception on the UI thread by adding the try/catch statement in the action that you pass to the `Invoke` method:

```
private void UpdateUI()
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            if (SecurityComponent.CurrentLoggedUser != null)
            {
                var user = SecurityComponent.CurrentLoggedUser;
                m_userLabel.Text = user.Username + " - " + user.Role.Name;
            }
            UpdateTerritories();
            ViewsIntegrationService.SetHmiMode(EHmiModes.Normal);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    });
}
```

If you put the try/catch around the call to the `Invoke` method, you get to handle the exception on the background thread. It makes more sense to put it around the actual code that may actually throw.

Comment: What about the option of registering to the event `DispatcherUnhandledException`, is that a possibility? Something like `App.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += new    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(method);`

Comment: This is not an option right now, but may be considered later.